# Use functions in a DLL without loading it?

Tags: c++, c, dll, linker, pcre

I am looking at some c++/c code, the open source ovaldi project. I see that they include pcre.dll in the distribution and are making calls to functions in that library in the code; but they never load the dll; they just include the pcre.h header and seem to have access to the functions. Are they really just building with a static library and distributing pcre.dll on accident or is there a way to do this?

Comment: You cannot run code without loading it into *some* process, even if that process isn't your own.  The CPU in most (all?) computers isn't capable of executing software off the disk without first loading it into RAM.

Comment: @Merlyn: "Loading" a library is much more than just copying it into memory, some code might be able to run from a copy, most also needs fixups, dependency processing, etc.

Comment: @Ben: "some code might be able to run from a copy" - Do you mean some code might be able to run without modifications, or that some code might be able to run off the disk?  My point isn't to illustrate the entire concept of what happens to code stored on disk (which you rightfully point out is much more complicated than simply cloning bits), but to illustrate that without copying it to memory, it can never be run.  That description matches a common high level definition of "loading".  Certainly not an answer, but a hint as to why you could never "not load" code.

Comment: @Merlyn: code can run from ROM without first being copied into RAM, but I was simply saying your point about having to get the code into memory doesn't require calling the OS "loader".  Code that hasn't been processed by the "loader" might be said to be "copied, not loaded".

Answer (score 8):

What do you mean they don't load the DLL?  Not calling `LoadLibrary`?  Probably are using an import table, the OS loader will load the DLL automatically.

Answer (score 4):

They DO load the dll, but just implicitly. You see, you can create a .lib file which is responsible for loading the dll and redirecting calls, link to the lib, include the header and that's it. In Visual Studio this is done automatically, when you set a dependency to a dll project

Answer (score 2):

The application itself can be built with linker indications to automatically find and load the DLL without needing to do so explicitly. True dynamic loading of DLLs is usually only needed when the question is which version of a DLL to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can load dynamic libraries at startup, but then you're required to restart the program to reload the library if the library changes.  Loading the library during runtime with `LoadLibrary` or `dlopen`(unix) allows you to update a dynamic library while the process is running.  This is good for long running processes such as a server, but it also incurs extra overhead for reloading the library.